# len() of itertools.product() before run the function in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a function itertools.product() that I need to know how many combinations this functions will provide before generate the combinations.

for example, if I have:

```
itertools.product(range(10), repeat=6)
```

i will have 1771561 possible combinations, or lines as a result

but I need to know this valeu before run this function. I don't know if exists some complexity analysis to this functions that show us this.

How I need to do to know this? Someone have any suggestions?

Comment: There is no way using itertools. Itertools only generates the sequence lazily. You should use math.

Comment: Please clarify your question. `itertools.product(10, repeat=6)` cannot even run, because it requires its first product to be iterable, did you mean `itertools.product(range(10), repeat=6)`? In that case, it would give you 10^6 tuples.

Comment: There isn't a general answer to this, iterators may have any (even infinite) length.

Comment: @jdehesa you are right. I didi the correto on the post. about the number of possible combinations I thought the same, but 10^6 = 1.000.000 and the function povides me 1.771.561 possible combinations, and is because this my question here.

Comment: That *doesn't* give you 1,771,561 combinations, as `sum(1 for _ in product(range(10), repeat=6))` will show.

Comment: sorry everyone, I found my error. @jdehesa was right. My function was consider 11^6, and no 10^6 as I was think. My question was solved. Thank you everyone!